# Repair options for beam notch

Tags: repair, beam

There is a beam of 15-18 inches depth and is notched by 5-6 inches within 1/3 of the corner from the bottom. What are possible options to reinforce this?

Comment: Picture? What is it supporting?

Comment: "What are possible options to reinforce this?"......limitless, because you gave us no details to narrow anything down.

Comment: You need professional engineering. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

A the level of detail provided - steel plates.

Nailed, structural-screwed or bolted if it's a timber beam, or welded if it's a steel beam (you're really not giving us much detail to work with here.) I suppose it could be concrete...